# Laravel Eloquent leftJoin within a whereIn query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

If I have something like the following, how can I add a left join to the "with(new Model)" part?

```
Model::whereIn('name', function ($query) use ($link) {
    $query->select('name')
        ->from(with(new Model)->getTable()) // would like to do a leftJoin here
        ->where('link', $link);
})->get();
```

I've tried

```
Model::whereIn('name', function ($query) use ($link) {
    $query->select('name')
        ->from(with(new Model)->leftJoin('tableZ', Model.col1, '=', tableZ.col1)->getTable())
        ->where('link', $link);
})->get();
```

I've also tried:

```
Model::whereIn('name', function ($query) use ($link) {
    $query->select('name')
        ->from(with(new Model)->getTable())
        ->leftJoin('tableZ', Model.col1, '=', tableZ.col1)
        ->where('link', $link);
})->get();
```

Not exactly sure how I'm supposed to go about doing this.

Comment: Maybe create desired raw SQL and post that as well. Install [debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and debug your SQL queries with the one you want to achieve. Have fun!

Comment: That debugbar looks pretty nifty. I'll check it out.

Comment: Its the first thing you should install... cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Is `link` a field in `tableZ`?  If so then

```
->where('table.link', $link)
```

might be what you want.  I'd use that in your second example; I don't think applying the `leftJoin()` directly to the `with` function works, as with() appears to return a model object, not a query.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should do this.

```
    DB::table("table_A")
    ->leftJoin("table_B","table_A.id,"=","table_B.A_id)
    ->select(['table_A.name as name','xxxxxx']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this may be solve your issue :

```
Model::whereIn('name', function ($query) use ($link) {
    $query->select('name')
        ->from(with(new Model)->getTable())
        ->leftJoin('tableZ', Model.col1, '=', tableZ.col1)
        ->where('tableZ.link', $link);
})->get();
```

Hope this work for you !!!